# Swift: Retrieve data from Firebase Database to label

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, uilabel, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get my data from Firebase Database to particular label in Swift. I have two labels in `TableView` (as `Main.storyboard`) tagged `1` and `2`.

In a `ViewController`, I have this code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct confStruct {
    let title : String!
    let place : String!
}

class EVS_Table_VC: UITableViewController {
    var conf = [confStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("conferences").queryOrderedByKey().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
                    snapshot in

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return conf.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

        let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = conf[indexPath.row].title

        let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel  
        label2.text = conf[indexPath.row].place

        return cell!

    }      
}
```

But nothing shows up in a Simulator. Does somebody have a proposition how to resolve this? This struct `confStruct` initializes my variable from 
Database? (`title`, `place`).

**JSON tree:**

```
"conferences": {
           "Key": {
              "date": "some date"
              "deadline": "some deadline"
              "place": "some place"
              "title": "some title"
                  }
               }
```

Comment: You need to append data from **snapshot** to **conf** before reloading table data

Comment: Give your JSON tree..

Comment: @Dravidian I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your struct to :-

```
   struct confStruct {
    let title : String!
    let place : String!

    init(title_String : String!, place_String : String!){

        self.title = title_String
        self.place = place_String
    }

}
```

And:-

```
  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("conferences/Key").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in


        if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            let titleS = snapDict["title"] as! String
            let placeS = snapDict["place"] as! String

            let temp = confStruct.init(title_String: titleS, place_String: placeS)
            self. conf.append(temp)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
```

Comment: I did what you said. But I also changed structure to work properly in swift 3. Thank you